# Pandoc error 10 when compiling document and fetching from fonts.gstatic.com

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc

I'm having trouble consistently compiling a particular document with `rmarkdown::render`. I cannot reproduce the issue reliably, unfortunately (it happens roughly 1/3 of the time), but when it fails, I get the error:

```
pandoc document conversion failed with error 10
```

from rmarkdown. The "10" is the return code from the system command that runs pandoc [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/10863429024e236389a48f40ab1485620d53d311/R/pandoc.R#L107).

When I set pandoc to give debugging information with `--verbose` the following lines are the last ones in stderr:

```
[INFO] Fetching https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v34/memvYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVTSKmu1aB.woff2...
[INFO] Fetching https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v34/memvYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVTSumu1aB.woff2...
[INFO] Fetching https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v34/memvYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVTSOmu1aB.woff2...
[INFO] Fetching https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v34/memvYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVTSymu1aB.woff2...
[INFO] Fetching https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v34/memvYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVTS2mu1aB.woff2...
[INFO] Fetching https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v34/memvYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVTSCmu1aB.woff2...
[INFO] Fetching https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v34/memvYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVTSGmu1aB.woff2...
Error : pandoc document conversion failed with error 10
```

The last line varies, but it always seems to be one of these fonts that is the last thing pandoc reports before the error (there are 24 of these font fetches in this particular document, as shown by the output in a successful compile).

This leads me to believe that there is a problem in fetching one of these fonts, but there's no output that says what the problem actually *is*, and Error 10 does not seem to be a valid error code from pandoc: [pandoc error codes](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/c9825761338f56209f69782da0087f9e27fa577b/src/Text/Pandoc/Error.hs#L154).

I'm sort of stuck debugging until I figure this out.

I also note there is a similar issue here: [NYTimes and 538 Themes Give Pandoc Error 10](https://github.com/jthomasmock/gtExtras/issues/89) - as a bonus, it even seems to be related to `fonts.gstatic.com`, but that out seems to be more specific, including a `[WARNING]` that I don't see in mine.

In case they are helpful, I've put the logs of a failure and success and the pandoc command that was run in a gist here: [logs](https://gist.github.com/richarddmorey/c88bdc16ddc37ac5ff4f34b68cfcdd70)

I'd appreciate any insights into what could cause this and how to fix it.

---

Edit to add command line:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS index.knit.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output index.html --lua-filter /Users/saprm3/Library/Caches/org.R-project.R/R/renv/library/flexTeaching3.api-91d1a6f0/R-4.2/aarch64-apple-darwin20/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter /Users/saprm3/Library/Caches/org.R-project.R/R/renv/library/flexTeaching3.api-91d1a6f0/R-4.2/aarch64-apple-darwin20/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/latex-div.lua --embed-resources --standalone --verbose --variable bs3=TRUE --section-divs --template /Users/saprm3/Library/Caches/org.R-project.R/R/renv/library/flexTeaching3.api-91d1a6f0/R-4.2/aarch64-apple-darwin20/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable theme=bootstrap --mathjax --variable 'mathjax-url=https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML' --include-in-header /var/folders/59/r7wjy0gn6yv59w19694x5gy80000gp/T//RtmpNWnHRc/rmarkdown-str16c6234aa443c.html
```

Comment: Please add the actual code of the document to your question, or a simplified version that still produces the error (even if it doesn't produce the error always). Also add the command line call you use to compile, or steps to reproduce in your editor and any relevant settings in case you don't use the command line. This will allow potential answerers to (try to) reproduce the error, which will increase the likelyhood of getting an answer to your question.

Comment: I've asked a question about what could generate Pandoc error 10. There's no error 10 in the Pandoc code. I'd be happy with an answer that simply told me what can generate that error, NOT how to fix my own code. That I can do myself. The pandoc command line is in the link at the bottom, as I say, but I'm happy to add it.

Comment: The idea is that to investigate what could generate Pandoc error 10, it is very helpful to be able to reproduce this error. Your code could be an easy way to do that, and maybe the only way because the error is a bit mysterious. Therefore it would be useful to add the document, or a simplified version of it, to the question.

Comment: However, wild guess: it might be just an error 1 (IOError) caused by a failed web connection, and the 0 got added by some other verbose output, maybe the exit code of the program itself (0 being 'normal exit').

Comment: @Marijn - I thought of the concatenation idea (10 is from 1+0) and ruled it out early, so I'm pretty sure that's not the case (unless R's system() command is doing it, which seems unlikely). I finally managed to get a reproducible version of the issue and suspect it may be an rmarkdown problem, so I've posted the full issue here: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/2495

Comment: This is an interesting issue. From your description however it may be that the problem is with Pandoc 3.1.2 on Mac and not with rmarkdown, so maybe posting it on https://github.com/jgm/pandoc would make sense as well? Note also that the latest version of Pandoc is 3.1.3, you might try that version (although I wouldn't expect this to fix the issue).

Comment: I updated to pandoc 3.1.3 and as you suspected, the problem still occurs. I also tried moving back to pandoc 3.1.1 (to match the bundled Rstudio 3.1.1 version) and it still occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a problem in the homebrew version of pandoc (https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/8779). Installing the non-homebrew release of pandoc, as suggested in the link, eliminates the error.